# How to fetch data in a tree structure in MySQL? In a single query

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL where each tuple in the table is a child of a tuple in the same table. For that, I'm inserting data primary Id as partner Id. Refer the following for an example.

[image]

Here 'A' parent has two children 'B' and 'C', similarly, 'B' has 'D' and 'C' has 'E' as their children respectively. An example is shown in below image

[image]

Now, coming to Question, I want to fetch all children of a given parent. Suppose if I pass `G`'s id 7, it should fetch `J`, `K` and `L` records. If I pass `A`'s id 1 it should fetch all records. How can I achieve this in a SQL query? I have no idea on how to build this MySQL query.

Answer (score 5):

This could be done using a recursive query as follows.

```
SELECT  id,
        name,
        parent 
FROM    (SELECT * FROM items
         ORDER BY parent, id) items_sorted,
        (SELECT @iv := '5') initialisation
WHERE   find_in_set(parent, @iv)
AND     length(@iv := concat(@iv, ',', id));
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0b7f5/1) to see this in action. Also, [this is a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query#33737203) that I have referred to, to create this answer.

Next time, please try to provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (perhaps an SQL Fiddle for a case like this) so that it is easy for someone who is willing to answer.